# How do I update my free apps when Apple ask me to "Review the updated Paid Applications Schedule"?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, contract

Summary: Do I need to accept the "Paid Applications" contract from Apple on iTunesConnect to update my free apps? If not, what are the steps I should follow to update my free app?

Details:

I'm trying to update a free app. I login to iTunes Connect and Apple show me this message:

[image: Review the updated Paid Applications Schedule]

I am the Team Agent, so I go to the 'Agreements, Tax, and Banking' section and I see:

1. In request amendment section, I have a "Paid Applications" type contract, it has a request button that I can click on
2. In contract in process section, I have a "Paid Applications" type contract
3. In contract in effect section, I have a "Free Applications" type contract. It's not expired yet

I only have free apps, how did I end up with 2 rows of paid contract here, can someone explain what might have happened?

I only want to update my free apps, can someone instruct me how to do so?

I don't want to click that request button request amendment section because the contract there says 'Paid Applications'. I'm afraid that this different contract will charge me extra money and ask me to agree different dangerous contract.

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you Paulw11, your comment addresses all my concerns.

Comment: Sorry, I actually have one more concern, If we must accept "Paid Applications" contract, then why do we have a "Free Applications" contract in the first place?

Comment: I just called Apple and they said a free contract will be fine for free apps. Do you have a pointer like url to the original document source that allows you to derive "Even if you only distribute free apps, you have the ability to distribute paid apps. If you don't accept the new agreement then you cannot distribute any new/updated apps, even free ones." please?

Comment: I guess I was wrong; I distribute both paid and free apps, so I just accept any updates as required.

Comment: After requesting and having "Paid Application" contact in effect, I no longer can see any new updated build version under the Build section of itunesconnect. I want to upload a new version of my free app and application loader says a "success" but its not visible in itunesconnect. I have waited for more than 3 weeks. Help?

Comment: Hi @MilanG, I don't know if your question is related to my question. Have you consider creating a new question for it? When in doubt, just call Apple dev support. If that's what you have done, then I think 3 weeks is a bit too long, I think my case got responded around 1 or 2 week if I remember correctly, and that solves my case indirectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the solution is to call Apple and ask them to change the contract type to the free one for you.

I found out that the reason that I have a paid contract pending when i only have free app is because someone in our team request a paid contract before.

Answer (score 1):

They are asking only to accept the terms and conditions of Paid Apps (For Future paid apps, they are agreeing you only). I just accepted after review the agreement and that's it.

**Steps:**

1- Open [itunesConnect.apple.com](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/) and sign in to your account.

2- Now Open Agreements, Tax and Banking Section

3- Now here, you can view edit and accept agreement, on right most side, view and accept two links, click on the second one, here a dialog will open, you have to select **I agree** and thats it.

4- Now you can upload, add versions to Itunesconnect.

[image]